# How do I modify android & iOS project to make the entry file as a common js file in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

As mentioned in the title, I wanna change the android entry file(index.android.js) and iOS entry file(index.ios.js) to a common js file named `index.js`, How do I modify in project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot achieve that currently. We will get the following error if we try to do so.

[image]

One way to simulate single entry point is by creating a container component having a single entry point your application like below

Application.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Component,
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

class Application extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Hello world</Text></View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Application;
```

and copy paste the same contents in index.ios.js and index.android.js

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import Application from './Application';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppName', () => Application);
```